# Saving a wpf treeview to text file

Tags: save, treeview, load, wpa

Please can you help
Have created a WPF treeView
Have button which adds nodes
Now how do we save the treeview for later loading

Have achieved this in winforms treeview using binary serialization
Have extnsively searched but no direct solutions